# How to get thumbnails and the download url of a file on Google Drive using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Apps Script, DriveApp interface on a Google Apps for Business account. When I access a valid file (Docs, JPEG or PNG)on Google Drive, the getThumbnail() return value is null. Is there something I should do to enable to generation of thumbnails?  Same problem with accessing the getDownloadUrl() for a file. I get a null even where I am the owner of the file.

What do I need to do to access the values for getThumbnail and getDownloadUrl?

Comment: Docs are different beasts from the image types you mention, you won't get download Urls for these. You need to `.getAs() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getAs(String). You get null for thumbnails if no thumbnail exists, calling the method won't create one for you.

Comment: The Thumbnail exists if I see the preview in Drive? I have a similar problem about null thumbnails, but the drive thumbnails list shows images for the files.